# Selenium Java Test Case not working

Tags: unit-testing, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I created one test case from FireFox and executed. It working fine,

I exported that as Java test case. I run in Eclipse, but it not working. I am getting error like this:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Incidents"}
```

My test case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://myapphost:8080/" />
<title>IncidentsListTest22</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">IncidentsListTest22</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/myapp/login/auth?usrMsg=SE</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=username</td>
    <td>username</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=password</td>
    <td>password</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=loginForm_submit</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Incidents</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

MY POM is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>myapp-selenium-test</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-selenium-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>Tests the UI for rmsportal.</description>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.39.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.39.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.39.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My test case is:

```
@Test 
public void testIncidentsList() throws Exception { driver.get(baseUrl + "myapp/login/auth?usrMsg=SE"); driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("username");
  driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
  driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm_submit")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Incidents")).click(); 
}
```

HTML page

```
<a class="dc-mega" href="#"> 
  Network Details 
  <span class="dc-mega-icon"></span> 
</a> 
<div class="sub-container non-mega" style="left: 138px; top: 31px; z-index: 1000;"> 
<ul class="sub" style="display: none;"> 
<li class="">
  <a href="/myapp/incident/list">Incidents</a> 
</li>
```

Comment: It tells you it can't find a link whose text is 'Incidents'. It will be difficult for us to help without viewing the DOM of the page at this moment (at least the source HTML where the element lives)

Comment: It working for with html test case. "Incidents" exist in html page, but not direct one it exist in one of the menu bar items"Details" tab.

Comment: My test case is    `@Test`
  `public void testIncidentsList() throws Exception {`
   `driver.get(baseUrl + "myapp/login/auth?usrMsg=SE");`
   `driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();`
   `driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("username");`
   `driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();`
   `driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");`
   `driver.findElement(By.id("loginForm_submit")).click();`
   `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Incidents")).click();`
  `}`

Comment: `<a class="dc-mega" href="#">`
`Network Details`
`<span class="dc-mega-icon"></span>`
`</a>`
`<div class="sub-container non-mega" style="left: 138px; top: 31px; z-index: 1000;">`
`<ul class="sub" style="display: none;">`
`<li class="">`
`<a href="/myapp/incident/list">Incidents</a>`
`</li>`

Answer (score 1):

`<a href="/myapp/incident/list">Incidents</a>` is a child of a `ul` tag that seems to be invisible (`<ul class="sub" style="display: none;">`) for webdriver. You'll have to make it visible first...

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is in my experience very flaky when finding elements. I recommend trying [XLT](http://www.xceptance.de/products/xlt/what-is-xlt.html) which has a very good Firefox plugin and exports JUnit testcases that you can run to test your page.

Comment: Selenium isn't flaky at all. It's up to the tester to know what is doing. I use Selenium on a massive basis, and always find a way to identify and find my elements